# Apex report pagination

Tags: pagination, report, reset, oracle-apex

I have a report that has multiple fields (e.g multiple text fields). The report also has pagination.The problem is when someone fill fields with information and uses the pagination ( default buttons next and previous) it clears them in the report. So if I fill information in page 1, then press the next button to fill some more information on the second page, and press the previous button, the information in page 1 is gone.

Also it may be relevant to know that the report has the partial refresh option active, because I need the results on it to be updated when some actions are used.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to submit your data before pagination. A more interactive manner would be to temporarly store your data in a collection.

[oracle docs on APEX_COLLECTION](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17556_01/doc/apirefs.40/e15519/apex_collection.htm)